# Heroku-Mandrill Addon: mandrill starter add on for heroku installation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, mandrill

I ran the following command

```
heroku addons:add mandrill:starter
```

I ran this command on my terminal as I read it in **Mandrill by Mailchimp** in **Heroku** Learning section. It says that mandrill stater is free but when I run this command on my terminal it says:

1. Please verify your account to install this add on plan.
2. For more information visit the **billing** page.

Do **heroku** have stopped the free service **or** there is something which I am missing?

```
                                 **OR**
```

Is it like I must be having a **premium account** on **heroku** to even install this free addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku requires you to verify your account to use add-ons. See their help center article for more details and reasoning: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification

Comment: if i do not have a paid account on Heroku, is it possible for me to use this add on?